# Redundant Server Application

Tags: linux, redundancy

I have two identical servers, they run linux and they have a  data base and a piece of software that is constantly recieving inputs. What is the right term that I should search for to be able to configure one as a redundant server - I mean when one fails the other one takes the job from where the first stopped.

Is it high availability the term that I am searching for? - Really new to this, so please help me.

Comment: What kind of results did you get when you tried googling it? That will tell you whether the term was right or not.

Answer (score 3):

Pacemaker will provide high availability for database and software. But to avoid split-brain you will need 3rd device as a witness (it can be even Raspberry Pi).

You can start with this link:
https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/

Answer (score 2):

`high availability` is the closest term to what you describe.

Also, depending on the software solution you will end up with, you need to look at things like `active-passive` or `active-backup` configuration, which just means you have servers dedicated for the load and servers doing nothing, but available in case the active one fails. This is to differential with `active-active` configuration which is interchangeable with `load balancing`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible search terms would be:

> Load-Balancing
>
> Disaster Recovery
>
> Horizontal Scaling

These terms describe some of the aspects that you're looking for mainly disaster recovery.